# How to use listActivity and mapActivity together

Tags: java, android

I use `MapActivity` and `ListActivity` together to display store location on map . Store comes from list. I use `setListAdapter(adapter)` but it won't support. Also I use `ListView` which gives `setAdapter(adpt)` but I get `Null pointer exception`.

Here is my code:

```
public void search(View view) {
    // || is the concatenation operation in SQLite
    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    try{    
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, store FROM storeInfo WHERE address LIKE         ?", 
    new String[]{"%" +   searchText.getText().toString() + "%"});
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, 
            R.layout.store_list_item, 
            cursor, 
            new String[] {"store"}, 
            new int[] {R.id.store});

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception::"+e);
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, StoreDetails.class);
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
        //Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
        intent.putExtra("STORE_ID", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the complete code... And I'm a little unsure of the flow of your app. Are you using a ListActivity where a user selects an item and then you open a MapActivity? You can't have a ListActivity and a MapActivity in one. You'll have to add either ListView or MapView into the appropriate activity. If your using a MapActivity you'll still need to call `setContentView()` and set your layout (which contains your MapView and ListView).

Depending on what you need to do, you could also use a ListFragment and define all of the logic and functionality required for your list in there and just add it to your MapActivity.

Comment: yeah it is seem uncompleted code and why need using ListActivity for displaying ListItem simple use ListView in MapActivty and populate it with BaseAdapter .. becoz for some reason you will need MapActivity but you can use listview in MapActivity .. not need to use both Activity